# I wrote a program on xcode using objective c. Can I run it on a windows machine?

Tags: ios, xcode, windows, macos

Thanks for your help.

I spent the last few months building a program in objective c, on my mac.  However, I would love to run it on a windows computer.  I don't need to run x-code, I just need to create an executable that will run on windows.

Is this possible?  Can I do this within x-code?

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

There is a new software being developed by Microsoft that will allow you to import Xcode projects written in Objective-C into Visual Studio. It was previously known as **Project Islandwood** and is now called **Windows Bridge for iOS.** A developer preview is available on [the website for the project](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/bridges/ios). This could be a possible solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need *VMWare* software installed in your windows system then you can download Xcode and you can run on it. There is no other option to run without Xcode.

Comment: So say I was interested in making a stand alone app and distributing it. This would be impossible?

Comment: Yes it is impossible i guess.